# ¿Cómo ignorar las tildes y mayúsculas al realizar busquedas?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite, framework

Tengo la información de los datos, como nombres, precios, etc; en una memoria estática, cuando los llamo en el buscador solo figuran sí son escritos exactamente como están el repositorio; mi duda es como ignorar las tildes y mayúsculas.

```
    @PostMapping("/buscar")
    public String buscarLibro(@RequestParam String nombre, Model model) {
   
    Collection<Libros> libros = librosService.findAll().stream().filter(p -> 

    p.getNombre().contains(nombre)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    model.addAttribute("bLibros",libros);
    
    return "/Libreria/listar";

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no quieres complicarte la vida puedes utilizar la libreria de apache commons-lang3, esta tiene una clase llamada StringUtils que resuelve tu problema facilmente

```java
    @PostMapping("/buscar")
    public String buscarLibro(@RequestParam String nombre, Model model) {
   
    Collection<Libros> libros = librosService.findAll().stream().filter(p -> 
    StringUtils.stripAccents(p.getNombre()).toLowerCase().contains(nombre.toLowerCase()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    model.addAttribute("bLibros",libros);
    
    return "/Libreria/listar";

   }
```

Para evitarte mas problemas con mayúsculas y minúsculas puedes agregar toLowerCase para transformar todo a minúsculas.

La dependencia en maven

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Y ademas de esto puedes probar la clase de java vanilla aunque es un poco menos elegante, pero no utilizas la libreria

```java
@PostMapping("/buscar")
    public String buscarLibro(@RequestParam String nombre, Model model) {
   
    Collection<Libros> libros = librosService.findAll().stream().filter(p -> 
    Normalizer.normalize(p.getNombre(), Normalizer.Form.NFD)
    .replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", "").toLowerCase()
    .contains(nombre.toLowerCase())).collect(Collectors.toList());

    model.addAttribute("bLibros",libros);
    
    return "/Libreria/listar";

   }
```

Comment: Es lo que intente al principio, pero luego al buscar elementos con tildes; simplemente no me lo muestra :(

Comment: Estas seguro? Acabo de probarlo y me funciona bien. Te puse la versión que utilice.

Comment: Que distraído soy!, estaba buscando como implementar lo que me mencionaste que no vi el código que compartiste. Lo probé y funciona !, pero ahora estoy pensando como lograr que lea con mayúsculas y tildes; ósea ambas opciones, que al buscar un producto con mayúsculas y tildes me muestre el resultado y también si busco con minúsculas y sin tildes.

Comment: @AngelloG_Delatorre Con agregar toLowerCase() ya es suficiente, también lo agregue en mi respuesta. Lo único, que no esta contemplado, es que si el parámetro de la request viene con tilde en este caso, habría un error, lo resuelves normalizando el parámetro de la lista de libros

Comment: Ya lo modifiqué; gracias desde el fondo de mi alma. Una ultima consulta, sabes donde puedo aprender a usar el Spring Framework desde lo más básico; llevó una semana con esto, pero aun tengo problemas para entenderlo a la perfección.

Comment: @AngelloG_Delatorre Bueno mi base de Spring la saque de youtube de los canales: pildorasinformaticas, mitocode y Amigoscode (El ultimo es un canal ingles). Estos son excelentes canales para aprender Java y Spring, y luego de esto cuando me salen dudas es por Google la mayoría de las veces terminas encontrando la respuesta en alguna pagina Indu (no es joda)

Comment: Gracias buen hombre por compartir sus experiencias.